# Creating a LiteDb database with a StorageFile argument

Tags: c#, uwp, windowsiot, litedb

I am trying to implement a database provider using LiteDb on my raspberry pi using UWP. It has an external hard drive attached and I would very much like to use it as a specific "Database" drive, to allow me to have a larger supported database size.

I am being passed a `StorageFile`, which is then to be used as my Database file. One constructor on LiteDb uses a stream (`System.IO.Stream`), is there anyway to convert the `StorageFile` object into a stream (derived from `System.IO.Stream`) in order to fulfill the new win10 security restrictions (requiring user permissions to access areas etc., preventing traditional File.Write/path based access to anything other than your application data directory).

Really am stuck, the option I have tried, which gives both read and write access to the `StorageFile` is:

```
var stream = storageProvider.StorageLocaton.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find any other methods which give both read/write access to the file as a stream.

Hopefully someone on here has a work around/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is there anyway to convert the StorageFile object into a stream...

You can use `StorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)` for writing and  `StorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)` for reading.

As for

> win10 security restrictions (requiring user permissions to access
>   areas etc., preventing traditional File.Write/path based access to
>   anything other than your application data directory).

You can utilize [PublisherCacheFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_GetPublisherCacheFolder_System_String_):

> The strong security model of Windows Runtime app typically prevents
>   apps from sharing data among themselves. It can be useful, however,
>   for apps from the same publisher to share files and settings on a
>   per-user basis. As an app publisher, you can register your app to
>   share a storage folder with other apps that you publish by adding
>   extensions to the app manifest.

The following code piece you can reference:

```
        StorageFolder sharedFonts = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("test");
        var testFile = await sharedFonts.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        var byteArray = new byte[] { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a };
        using (var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray).AsRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (var destinationStream = (await testFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)).GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(sourceStream, destinationStream);
            }
        }

        var readArray = new byte[100];
        using (var destinationStream = new MemoryStream(readArray).AsRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (var sourceStream = (await testFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)).GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(sourceStream, destinationStream);
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

You can convert `IRandomAccessStream` to `System.IO.Stream` like this:

```
Stream writeStream = destinationStream.AsStreamForWrite();

Stream readStream = sourceStream.AsStreamForRead();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, with regards to creating a stream, the stream returned by OpenAsync is of type `IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStream>`, unfortunately, not compatible with System.IO.Stream that the constructor supports. Looking at the `PublisherCacheFolder` information, its a way of specifying folder paths, i cannot find any information online to indicate whether you can give it a whole path to an external drive? Is that possible through using `D:\folder` in the xml configuration? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` to get the external drive.

Comment: yes i have the storage file object for the removable drive already, just needed a way to get a stream to use the external drive as a database directory rather than the path, which i think will prohibit access.

Comment: It looks like there are multi questions. Please check the update of my  answer of converting `IRandomAccessStream` to `System.IO.Stream` To be clear, you can show your code in your question and point out where you are stuck or what error info you get.

Comment: Thanks, that addition works to convert the `RandomAccessStream` to `IO.Stream`, not sure where the confusion is about my question as I did mention that I was getting the `IAsyncOperation<RandomAccessStream>`, needed a `System.IO.Stream`, with the purpose of writing an external drive that I already had the access to and was being provided a `StorageFile` object of. The code I provided was the entire problem I had, an `OpenAsync` would return the wrong type of stream required for the LiteDb constructor. Thanks for your help, sorry if I caused confusion?